# Anyone using Neo4j Embedded (v 1.8.x) with JDK 7?

Tags: neo4j, java-7

I would like to know if anyone is using Neo4J 1.8.x Embedded with Sun JDK 7?  IF so, have you hit any issues and what are they?

Let me also clarify, I'm not looking to build the Neo4J source code - only run Neo4j 1.8.1 Embedded on Sun Java 7.

I know that Neo4j 1.9 is the first version that will support Java 7, but if Neo 1.8.1 runs on Sun JDK 7 without any problems, we will be considering deploying with that.

There are a number of benefits (i.e. security, etc.) to going with Java 7, but if there are compatibility issues with Neo 1.8.1, we'd like to find out.

Thanks,
Bob

Comment: we fixed a number of issues with java7, one that's still open is the sorting consistency of memory mapped pages required by TimSort.

Comment: Hi Michael, can you confirm: were these problems that were introduced by running Neo4J 1.8 on Java7, or did this problems exist even when running on Java 6?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Java 7 has changed the built in sorting algorithm. The new sorting algorithm ([TimSort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort)) is more sensitive to concurrent modification. Where the sorting algorithm in Java 6 and earlier would just produce a result that wasn't perfectly sorted in the face of concurrent modification, TimSort will throw an exception.

Neo4j uses these `sort()` methods in its page cache.

These exceptions means that Neo4j will crash unexpectedly when running with multiple threads on Java 7.

The Neo Technology team are addressing this issue for Neo4j 1.9.

Comment: Does that mean if you are not running a multithreaded application, then you shouldn't have any problems with neo4j 1.8 and java 7?